# 'jumpTo' vs 'navigate' in React (Native) Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

Using React Navigation, different types of Navigators have different actions for (programmatically) navigating between screens.

For e.g. the StackNavigator, the 'pop', 'push' etc. have well-documented (different) behavior, compared to the common 'navigate' action.

But for the Drawer and TabNavigators, we have the option to use 'jumpTo'. I fail to understand **how 'jumpTo' is different from 'navigate', and when to use what?**

[Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-actions#jumpto) just says

> The jumpTo action can be used to jump to an existing route in the
> drawer navigator.

What benefit does that have compared to '[navigate](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#navigate)', which

> ...allows to navigate to a specific route

So more specifically, using a DrawerNavigation, how does this

```
props.navigation.navigate('Create meeting')
```

... work differently from this

```
props.navigation.jumpTo('Create meeting');
```

... and when should I use which?

Answer (score 0):

Use "JumpTo" when you want to navigate directly to a specific screen or route and you don't need to preserve the navigation history. For example, you might use it to go to a login screen after a user session has expired or to reset the navigation stack to a certain screen.

Use "Navigate" when you want to navigate between screens in a sequential manner, allowing users to go back to the previous screen. It's useful for creating a navigation flow within your app where users can move forward and backward through screens.

Comment: Thanks for answering, even after all this time.

What you're saying makes a lot of sense. Having an option to go somewhere, while also clearing the "back"-history, could be super helpful in some cases, and that behavior would align well with the function-naming.

However, I just tested it again, and it does not seem to work that way. I can still go back to the previous page, after navigating with "jumpTo".

Additionally, it seems like the "jumpTo"-function have been removed from Navigation 6, so it may have just been an oversight or leftover from previous versions?

Comment: @ChrisJohansen Yes, in navigation 6 "JumpTo" is removed but still we can use it in previous versions. In navigation 6 we can achieve similar functionality using the navigate function or the reset function provided by the navigation prop.